Есть ли какая-то консольная утилита в Linux, способная сравнить два HTML-файла по степени похожести?
Есть два HTML-кода. В одном - статья на одном сайте, в другом - копия этой статьи на другом сайте, прошедшая некие html/xml преобразования. То есть, до и после текста статьи - все в коде разное (header/bottom), да и сам текст статьи на разных сайтах отформатирован разными тегами. И еще текст статьи тоже может немного отличаться.
Так вот, есть ли какая-то консольная утилита, которая покажет некую метрику, через которую можно (хотя бы с некоторой долей вероятности) понять, что эти два HTML-кода содержат одинаковую статью? Или что один HTML-код содержит часть статьи (достаточно крупную) с другой страницы?
Чтобы в утилите была какая-то реализация string kernels или косинусного подобия или чего-то такого.

Банально выкинуть весь html-код и сравнить оставшийся текст любым удобным способом?

"Любым удобным способом" - каким? В этом и состоит вопрос. Пока что я вижу только возможность через готовую реализацию алгоритма Оливера (Programming Classics: Implementing the World's Best Algorithms by Oliver ISBN 0-131-00413-1), реализованную в PHP в функции similar_text(). Но может быть есть какие-то готовые консольные инструменты.

diff покажет вам различия, sha256sum даст вам метрику
